# *ngIf is not rendering svg as intended

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, rendering

I'm trying to conditionally render svg icons using *ngIf. I've imported CommonModule and BrowserModule to the component but every time I run the code the svg is not rendering as it should be.

HTML template code:

```
<svg *ngIf="!filename" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="black" class="bi bi-file-earmark-x" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M6.854 7.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708L7.293 9l-1.147 1.146a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708L8 9.707l1.146 1.147a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L8.707 9l1.147-1.146a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8 8.293z"/>
          <path d="M14 14V4.5L9.5 0H4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h8a2 2 0 0 0 2-2M9.5 3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 11 4.5h2V14a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H4a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h5.5z"/>
</svg>
```

Component code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-quiz-generator',
  templateUrl: './quiz-generator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quiz-generator.component.scss'],
})
export class QuizGeneratorComponent {
  isPdf = false;
  filetype = '';
  filename = '';
}
```

I've tried using different conditions such as `*ngIf="filename == false"` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Your commonModule is imported in which component ?

Comment: It's imported in the QuizGeneratorModule which has the QuizGeneratorComponent as a declaration

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I forgot to import the QuizGeneratorModule into the main AppModule. All is working now!